Where does graph API get information about organization city and state
I am using Microsoft Graph api "/organization". It returns invalid data in "city" and "state" fields for the organization. Where does this API get the information from?
This API:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization
The value returned (invalid):
{
  ....
  "id": "....",
  "city": "New York",
  "state": null,
  "street": null,
  ....
}

Where do I fix that information?

I had a test to update the city and state property of the organization, but the result told me that these 2 properties are not allowed to update. I'm afraid these are set when creating the tenant. By the way, I also didn't find these properties in Azure portal....

@TinyWang exactly the same experience for me. I can't believe you set these when creating a tenant and cannot modify later. Organizations move, do they not? The data from Microsoft 365 (admin.microsoft.com) is not used

Yeah.. but I'm not an expert here so that... hmmm I mean maybe these 2 fields are designed like this but for scenarios like "Organizations move", azure might provide another solution, but I don't know that....In some terms I have to say it's really complex for normal use and the design might be designed for some other unnormal scenarios...

The "city" and "state" fields for an organization can be updated in the Microsoft 365 admin center. I have just tested this and got the data seconds later
To update this information, follow these steps:

Sign in to the Microsoft 365 admin center using an account with
administrator permissions.
Navigate to "Settings"
Select Org Settings
Select Organization Profile Tab
Click Organization Information
Update the "city" and "state" fields as needed and save your changes.

Note that it may take some time for the updated information to be reflected in the data returned by the Graph API.

You can find more details about the organization resource type in the Microsoft Graph documentation.
Note that currently, Microsoft Graph API does not support write operations to the /organization endpoint. You cannot update these details programmatically through the API.
